# Проблема после Build-а игры на Android

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Сама игра запускается, но на экране видно только главного персонажа и платформы, которую даже не создавал я. В самом Unity всё работает хорошо.
[image: Показывает так]

[image: Должно быть так]

Comment: Возможно, дело в разных сценах (File -> BuildSettings -> Scenes In Build). Вероятно, когда Вы делали давно первый тестовый билд, то добавили в сборку какую-нибудь тестовую сцену с этой платформой и персонажем. А потом, когда появилась "рабочая" сцена, Вы по-прежнему собираете проект со старой сценой.

Comment: Ыаа, так и есть. Переименовал сцену, сохранил, и та сцена пропала( можно ли вернуть ее?

Comment: Без бэкапа или какой-нибудь GIT - вряд ли....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, дело в разных сценах

```
(File -> BuildSettings -> Scenes In Build)
```

Вероятно, когда Вы делали давно первый тестовый билд, то добавили в сборку какую-нибудь тестовую сцену с этой платформой и персонажем. А потом, когда появилась "рабочая" сцена, Вы по-прежнему собираете проект со старой сценой.